# Как получить\удалить\изменить метаданные с файла в Linux?

Tags: linux, безопасность

А зачем это вообще делать ? Прежде чем загрузить фотографию в Интернет, удалите из файла свои личные данные, скрытые в метаданных (или Exif). В них содержится информация не только о том, когда был сделан снимок, но и покажут ваши данные GPS, по которым можно вычислить ваш адрес, если фото было сделано дома.

1. Как получить метаданные файла ?
2. Как удалить метаданные файла ?
3. Как изменить метаданные файла ?

Comment: Подозреваю, что вопрос слишком общий, нет примеров кода, конкретного описания проблемы, нет описания ваших попыток и догадок. Возможно вам поможет - [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: О каких метаданных речь?

Comment: @stackflow владельца файла позволяет узнать `ls -l`, кто-то что-то явно путает

Comment: @stackflow это мы вас спрашиваем :)

Comment: @stackflow вот про эту всю суть и должно быть написано в самом тексте вопроса

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654281/how-to-remove-exif-data-without-recompressing-the-jpeg

Comment: @stackflow, а я и не имею к вам никаких претензий. Просто на всякий случай оставил комментарий (а правила предписывают дать вместо этого ответ), чтобы люди, может быть, знающие английский на троечку, могли найти больше вариантов. Потом, я слышал, что проводится эксперимент по идентификации одинаковых/похожих вопросов на разных языках.

Comment: Вообще-то, вопрос (и последующий самоответ) отвратительно сформулированы. Совершенно не понятно в результате, они (эти метаданные) в [xattr - Extended attributes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/xattr.7.html) лежат или в отдельной секции файла (.jpg ?) с фотографией.

Comment: Скорее я решу его заминусовать (если автор не исправит (или я про него не забуду -))

Comment: @stackflow раз уж не поленились поделиться, можно было бы не полениться и в глубь походить

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Как получить метаданные файла

Получить метаданные с **одного** файла: 
`mat -d Example.jpg` # *sudo apt-get install mat*

Проверить на метаданные **все** файлы в папке:

```
mat -c Название_папки
```

> 2. Как удалить метаданные файла ?

Удаление метаданных с **одного** файла: 
`mat leakedmegatrack.mp3`

Удаление метаданных для **всех** файлов в папке:

```
mat Название_папки
```

*Про **mat** я узнал c этих источников:*
[youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5J_tA65cNbI)
[rus-linux.net](http://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/sec/How-to-remove-file-metadata-on-Linux.html)
[zalinux.ru](https://zalinux.ru/?p=96)

Comment: Не загуглив, что умеет прога `mat`, невозможно понять, о чём вообще речь

Comment: Пока вы не написали про exif — да, невозможно. Повторюсь: `ls -l` показывает владельца файла, а вот `mat` его НЕ показывает, такие дела. И exif тут был ни при чём, пока я вас не заставил о нём написать

Comment: Хоть бы ссылку на manpage этой команды привели

Comment: Про mat первый раз слышу, https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/ куда популярней вродею

Comment: @Hellseher тут прикол в том, что mat умеет ещё несколько других форматов помимо джипега с exif, например mp3. Но естественно stackflow не потрудился об этом рассказать :\

Comment: Есть ещё утилита *exiv2*: 

exiv2  is  a program to read and write Exif, IPTC, XMP metadata and image comments and  can read many vendor makernote tags. The  program  optionally  converts  between  Exif tags,  XMP  properties and IPTC datasets as recommended by the Exif Standard, the IPTC   Standard, the XMP specification and Metadata Working Group guidelines.